# Combine Wordpress site search results with product search results on one page

Tags: wordpress, search, woocommerce

On my Wordpress website, a site search that is limited to only posts renders a perfect results display of posts.  A product search also renders a perfect display of products, although displayed differently. But if I attempt to search for both posts and products, the display is terrible.  I think the products are probably forced into the posts display template.  Since each of my products includes an explanation post inside the product description, those posts are repeated after every product -- mighty ugly. I don't need any product descriptions to be shown the results and prefer all products to be displayed like they are in the only product search.

This is all visible if you search for 'Grace' using the three different search inputs at this testing post: https://www.hebrewwordpics.com/dummypost/

I want to use only one search input form that will do both searches and display them together sequentially on one page.

Using WooCommerce and StoreFront child theme.  Currently limiting searches with Ivory Search plugin, but the results are similar with other plugins or none at all.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] so that we have a way to help you.

Comment: Thanks for responding but the only reproducible example I know how to provide is in the link to my dummy search example post.  It will demonstrate the results of the three different searches.  If I need to provide code for some parts of that, I will need help to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `get_post_type()` to identify which post type is being queried. Then display a specific template per post type.

> ### get_post_type( int|WP_Post|null $post = null )
>
> Retrieves the post type of the current post or of a given post.

| Parameter | Description |
| --- | --- |
| **$post** | *(int/WP_Post/null) (Optional)* Post ID or post object. Default is global $post. Default value: null |

You can use the following on your search page.

```
<?php
if ( 'post' === get_post_type() ):
  // ... post template
elseif ( 'product' === get_post_type() ):
  // ... product template
else:
  // ... else
endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks @amarinediary. I think we know which post type is being queried but I don't know which file holds the template being used to display the results.  I suspect posts search use a different template than products search uses.  I'm starting to think that products use the woocommerce archive-products.php file because the search results look the same as every other product display.

Comment: archive is used to display product categories. search is used to display search result.